# NAT one network to another using iptables

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, nat, route

Trying to NAT ips in different network using iptables.

KVM host with ip 10.10.11.36 on bridge br0.

Two vms are running with ip 192.168.11.60 and 192.168.11.57 sharing bridge br0.

Want to NAT all request coming on 10.10.11.60 to 192.168.11.60.

How can this be done with out using SNAT.

tried this:

On host bridge br0 created an alias br0:0 with ip 192.168.11.36 and specified this in guest as gateway.

NAT rule.

```
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             10.10.11.60         to:192.168.11.60
```

ofcourse rule counter is not increasing,

How to make NAT work here?

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: NAT is not working

Comment: You mean All requests coming on 10.10.11.36 to 192.168.11.60?  Since you never mentioned 10.10.11.60  I assume you made a typo.

Comment: no as i mentioned 10.10.11.60 to 192.168.11.60.

Comment: You still have not asked a question! Hint: a question is an interrogative statement followed by an eroteme (?).

Comment: `ofcourse rule counter is not increasing,` Show us all your rules.

Comment: @fukawi2 this is the only rule,and default policy is accept

Comment: Well if that is the case and that counter isn't going up, there are no packets reaching the box destined for 10.10.11.60 so the rule isn't your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mention two network connected to same bridge?

It can not work create two bridges one for 10.10.11 and other for 192.168.11

then try your NAT ing rule